# Java Streams: Collect not combining all values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of buckets, with each bucket containing a number of records. I'm using streams to sum values of these records in each of these buckets. However, I've run into a problem where after my `collect` the sums are incorrect. Here my processing statement thus far:

```
List<StatAccumulator> results = statData.stream().map(
            list -> list.stream().parallel()
            .collect(
                () -> new StatAccumulator(metrics, groups),
                StatAccumulator::containerize,
                StatAccumulator::combine
            )
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The StatAccumulator is just a container class that stores each of the values I'm summing for each record.

```
public class StatAccumulator {
    public StatRecord result;
    private final List<String> metrics;
    private final List<String> groups;
    private Long count;

    public StatAccumulator(List<String> metrics, List<String> groups) {
        this.metrics = metrics;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    public void containerize(StatRecord initial) {
        //logger.info(initial.toString());
        this.result = new StatRecord(
            initial.v1,
            initial.v2
        );
        this.count = 1l;
    }

    public void combine(StatAccumulator other) {
        result.v1+= other.result.v1;
        result.v2+= other.result.v2;

        this.count += other.count;
        logger.info("Current Combined: "+this.result.v1.toString());
    }
}
```

For simplicity's sake, I am working with only one bucket and tracking only one value. Before going into this processing step, I output all the values of every record and summed them in Excel to get an expected result (~28k) but I tend to get an actual result of ~5k. So, I've confirmed all the data is going in, but not all of it is coming out. Does anyone know why I would be missing results?

Comment: `this.count = 1l;` should probably be `this.count++`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your containerize method is incorrect. It should be

```
public class StatAccumulator {
    public StatRecord result = new StatRecord(0, 0);
    private final List<String> metrics;
    private final List<String> groups;
    private long count;

    public StatAccumulator(List<String> metrics, List<String> groups) {
        this.metrics = metrics;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    public void containerize(StatRecord other) {
        //logger.info(initial.toString());
        this.result.v1 += other.v1,
        this.result.v2 += other.v2
        this.count++;
    }

    public void combine(StatAccumulator other) {
        result.v1+= other.result.v1;
        result.v2+= other.result.v2;
        this.count += other.count;
        logger.info("Current Combined: "+this.result.v1.toString());
    }
}
```

`containerize` is used to accumulate results, from an initial state. It's the only method that is used when the stream is sequential.

`combine` is only used when the stream is parallel, to combine the accumulated results of two "sub-streams".

Comment: Ooh, I think my issue was I thought containerize was called for each element of the stream, but it's only called once per thread, correct?

Comment: No. It's called many times per threads: once per element of the sub-stream handled by the thread.

Comment: I'm sorry, I said that wrong. What I meant to say was I thought the collect function used `containerize` to initialize a NEW `StatAccumulator` for each element of the stream, essentially mapping each element to a container. Looking back it seemed silly to me that `collect` would want to construct the container and initialize in a different steps.

Comment: …and since `metrics` and `groups` are entirely unused, removing them from the `StatAccumulator` class allows replacing the supplier `() -> new StatAccumulator(metrics, groups)` with the much simpler `StatAccumulator::new`…

Comment: They're not actually unused, I sanitized that class before posting, just didn't remove those.